# vertical-align:middle doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I just want to place images in a fixed-height container: images must not exceed container's height and must be centered vertically.

So I have

```
<div id="partenaires"> 
    <img src="images/partenaires/Debian.png" alt="Debian" /> 
    <img src="images/partenaires/Fedora.png" alt="Fedora" /> 
    ... 
</div>
```

with

```css
#partenaires { 
    height:3em; 
    line-height:3em; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    clear:both; 
} 
#partenaires img { 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    margin:0 1em; 
    max-height:100%; 
}
```

But it appears big images are truncated on bottom like this (for all browsers) because `vertical-align`:

[image]

How I should do to what I want? I really don't understand this behaviour...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: you can try all you want [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RgTaY/)!

Comment: `height:3em; overflow: hidden` makes this somewhat expected I think. Can you remove the overflow rule?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm using it to implement a slider. But I'm sure the height of images is indeed that of the container, they are just not centered vertically!

Comment: @Mat what happens if you remove the `line-height`?

Comment: Big images are correctly displayed but smaller are on the top of the container. Same if I remove vertical-align rule.

Comment: It's fine if I removed `line-height` (http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/rgLNN/)

Comment: @Jeaffrey Gilbert Only for images which are heigher than the container, they appear centered because they take entire height, but less-height images are on the top.

Comment: @Michael same thing, I REALLY don't understand..! (I've added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RgTaY/)

Comment: What about http://jsfiddle.net/RgTaY/8/ ?

Comment: I've made a mistake in my second comment: without vertical-align little images are in the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should use a line-height value of 2.7em because lines have some extra space above and below them so a line-height of 3em won't fit in a div of height 3em which is why your images are getting cropped.

edit: 2.78 seems good.

Answer (score 1):

you can use align="absmiddle" rather than vertical-align:middle;

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:baseline;` works as expected (note: I tried only on Safari and FF) or remove `overflow:hidden` from container (if you defined for clearing purpose just change clearing method)

Comment: Almost same behavior but little images are in the bottom.

Comment: Read my first comment. If correct behavior cannot be achieved I'll try another structure.